# Passing value from one viewmodel to sub viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using .Net FW 4.5, VS 2013 and SQLITE. I've got a "MainWindow" that contains tab items. Each tab item has it's own view and each view has its own VM. I am running a query on my MainWindow that returns data to a datagrid. Depending on which "SelectedItem" is selected I need my query to return relevant sub data to my tab which contains my view/viewmodel... how do I get my main VM to pass a value to my Sub-VM... I've tried "FindVisualParent" but it does not work. I think it's loading up my value after everything is loaded and therefore not applying my filer on my sub-VM query... Hope this makes sense.

Best methods applicable to MVVM would be appreciated. 
[Download Sample Code](http://1drv.ms/17ckTQs)

Comment: Did you consider raising an event in your "main" viewmodel and having event handlers in the "sub" viewmodels?

Comment: a little bit of code showing how things are wired together would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, your view's View Model should instance each of the child view models and hold references to them as properties. Then your Tab's data context can be assigned to the view model property in the main windows view model.

This lets your parent view model register for change notification's in your child view models and gives you more control over how they interact.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess without seeing any code is that your views own (instantiate) their respective view models. That would explain why you are using FindVisualParent to get at the other view models. Try having your main view model instantiate your child view models.